# Migrating from AWS S3 to GCP: Uploading Files in Chunks and Stitching with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I previously developed a system using Spring Boot, which utilized AWS S3 for uploading files in chunks. The workflow involved obtaining an upload ID, generating a signed URL for each chunk, and then stitching the uploaded chunks together with a call to my Spring Boot server. However, I have recently migrated to Google Cloud Platform (GCP), and I'm unsure how to replicate this functionality as there doesn't seem to be a direct equivalent resource in GCP.

Here are the key steps I followed with AWS S3:

1. Obtaining an upload ID for file uploads.
2. Generating a signed URL for each chunk using the upload ID.
3. Uploading the file chunks to AWS S3 using the signed URLs.
4. Stitching the uploaded chunks together on the server side with a call to my Spring Boot server.

I would like to achieve a similar file upload mechanism using GCP's storage service. Can someone provide guidance on how to accomplish this with GCP? Specifically, I need assistance with the following points:

1. How can I obtain an upload ID or a similar identifier in GCP for chunked file uploads?
2. Is there an equivalent to generating signed URLs for each chunk in GCP, and if so, how can I implement it?
3. What would be the best approach to upload the file chunks to GCP's storage service using the generated URLs?
4. Lastly, how can I stitch the uploaded file chunks together on the server side using Spring Boot with GCP?

Any assistance or suggestions on achieving this file upload workflow in GCP with Spring Boot would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The Google Cloud Storage equivalent is `Composite Objects`. I do not know the Java SDK but general information is [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects) and the JSON API is [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose).

Comment: @JohnHanley, GCP has the worst documentation I have ever encountered in this industry. For instance, when I receive a 400 HTTP status code as a response, and I refer to the GCP documentation to investigate the issue, I am presented with approximately 66 potential scenarios. This is equivalent to implying that one can never truly ascertain the reason behind receiving such a response. I deeply regret having migrated from AWS.

Comment: Imagine being a lawyer or doctor and you must memorize a shelf of books and take a huge certification before you can have your first job. We have it easy in comparison.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I found a solution to my issue today, and I'm relieved. While I understand your point about certain fields being more challenging than programming, it's important to note that acknowledging difficulties in other fields doesn't mean engineers should be praised just because their work is less hard. Comparing platforms like GCP and AWS, user experience and ease of use should be considered. If other platforms provide a more user-friendly and intuitive experience, it raises questions about why GCP shouldn't be equally easy to use. As a user, we expect usability and clear documentation.

Comment: I agree with you that documentation can be improved. I have been working with AWS and GCP for more than 10 years. I find both equally easy to work with. I have no problem with their documentation. It is rare that I cannot find what I need. For example, I am now working with a new C++ GCP SDK. In the beginning, I was struggling to understand as I had expectations from working with other SDKs. I decided to read every single page, including the source code, and practiced. Now, I think that the documentation is very good and the SDK is amazing. Experience and perspective changed my opinion.